# Why we use Pickle instead of saving the weights in HDF5 format in Deep Learning

Tags: machine-learning, pickle

I have read that, Pickle library is used to save trained model into a *.pkl* file to use it later.
Also, we can save the weights of a trained model into a hdf5 format using

```
model.save()
```

and use those weights afterwards.

So why we use pickle instead of hdf5 files?

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2021 neither pickle nor h5 is recommended (while h5 is still supported by Keras/TF).

[The docs say](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize):

> There are two formats you can use to save an entire model to disk: the
> TensorFlow SavedModel format, and the older Keras H5 format. The
> recommended format is SavedModel. It is the default when you use
> model.save()

Answer (score 0):

Avoid pickle, there are a couple of [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752259/python-why-pickle)

Even in keras documentation they say

"It is not recommended to use pickle or cPickle to save a Keras model."

Also look at this [solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928794/which-is-faster-for-load-pickle-or-hdf5-in-python)